# JETSTREAM "Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css." ERROR

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

firstly i want to explain how I`m install laravel and jetstream.

I open a folder from c disk, and i am goes to this folder from cmd and I start to write these codes

laravel new project --jet, it ask to me livewire or inertia, I say livewire,

It building project and I migrate my database on xamp.
I can reach this screen.

[image]

As you can see there is a login button from top right, when I click this button this screen comes out.

[image]

And these are files from installation.

[image]

Also I have a laravel project with jetstream, when i start server with this project it works well.
But I can not install jetstream with new project.

I`m a new with this world, please help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have `resources/css/app.css`?

Comment: If you do not, [edit your vite.config.js](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#configuring-vite) and remove that line

Answer (score 5):

I found something interesting.

I write `npm run dev` on a different terminal from project folder. Jetstream starts working, when I close terminal which is I wrote `npm run dev`, jetstream crashes again.

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes, that's how Vite works. `npm run dev` hosts assets for development use. Nothing will work if it's not running, unless you do `npm run production` to generate permanent assets.

Comment: Thanks, but npm run production not working :d. says npm ERR! Missing script: "production", same thing with npm run prod

Comment: Looks like it's `npm run build`. Always check `package.json` for the available commands; looks like they ditched `npm run production`.

Comment: So simple and so useful, thanks @ÖzgürÇoban

Answer (score 1):

For me it works only when I run

```
npm run dev
```

and I let it run in the background. If I stop it, I am getting the same error.

Or if you dont want to let it run (like in a production env), you run

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

composer require laravel/breeze:1.11.1

instead of

composer require laravel/breeze

Maybe the version of breeze in laravel should be specific. I've tried that and it works

Comment: Jetstream is the alternative for breeze. So i think it's unrelated

Comment: I need livewire, breeze is working also but livewire run build every time

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because while compiling the assets the *Manifest.json* file inside the *public/build* folder has a small typo in the directories.
You may find that instead of resources/css/app.css it would be written as:

> resources/css\\app.css

Just change it back to *'resources/css/app.css'* and you will be fine. All the assets were compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using @vite call css and js like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/public/build/assets/app.67dcdfd2.css') }}">

<script src="{{ asset('/public/build/assets/app.87a4a3cb.js') }}"></script>
```

get your CSS and js file from the build folder and replace It

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help...
Once you install the laravel application and implement the jetstream livewire, run the following commands:

1. php artisan migrate -- to migrate the tables.
2. npm install
3. npm run dev
4. php artisan serve

These should clear the error "Unable to locate file in Vite manifest:resources/css/app.css"

Comment: I wrote npm run dev, and works, but in my old project when i close terminal, project was running well, this time crashes, probably new jetstream version problem.